# Jqtree - ordering entrys

Tags: javascript, sorting, jqtree

I am using the jqtree plugin to generate a treeview.
Now I want to sort the tree for every node via the label.

The plugin comes without a sort function so I think I need to sort it before I load the data into it.

This is my data to sort.

```
[
{
    "label": "A label",
    "id": "201",
    "children": [
        {
            "label": "C Label",
            "id": "40773",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": "F label",
                    "id": "222460",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "label": "C label",
                    "id": "222469",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "label": "X label",
                    "id": "27512",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "F label",
                            "id": "143546",
                            "children": []
                        },

                        {
                            "label": "D label",
                            "id": "141341",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": "G label",
                                    "id": "222456",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "L label",
                                    "id": "222457",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "x label",
                                    "id": "222443",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "label": "Z label",
                                            "id": "222447",
                                            "children": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "label": "A label",
                                            "id": "222446",
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "L label",
                                    "id": "222455",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "A label",
                            "id": "143547",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": "B label",
                                    "id": "222458",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "R label",
                            "id": "143548",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function that iterates through your tree and any sort of sorting algorithm to sort them.

```
recursiveSortByLabel(arr); //arr = the array with your tree data
function recursiveSortByLabel(obj){
    if(obj.length > 0){
        for(var i in obj){
            if(obj[i].children.length > 0)
                recursiveSortByLabel(obj[i].children);
            sortAlgorithm(obj); //any sorting algorithm
        }
    }
}
```

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnvwom7b/1/) i did it with the rather unefficient but easy to implement bubblesort algorithm. It logs the result to the console for inspectation.